# why ">/dev/null" works differently when it's used for a command line and for a file?

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

I'm struggling with understanding '>', '2>&1', '>&2',... these things.

Could anyone please explain why these two results are different?

```
$ cat test
echo a
echo b >&2

$ ./test >/dev/null
b

$ echo b >&2 >/dev/null
$
```

any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should add a shebang in your scripts.... also  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055

Comment: @Jetchisel thank you so much for a nice article. Its explanation is very clear! But the result is the same even if I use shebang in the file 'test'. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Could you please tell me how I can exactly use shebang in the above example?

Comment: That link did not explain everything? The former you're only directing `stdout` to `/dev/null ` the latter you're directing both `stderr` and `stdout` to `/dev/null` redirection is evaluated from `left`  to `right` Other than that I don't know what to tell you since that link covers it all imo.

Comment: @Jetchisel well, that link explains redirection clearly, but it doesn't address what I'm asking in this question. My point is, why it's different 1)when `echo b >&2` is "inside" of a file and 2)written in the command line. The former is very well explained in your link, but I think the latter runs a little bit differently. In the latter case, the `stdout` "pointer" changes to point /dev/null, while the former doesn't(keep pointing `&2`). Please let me know if I'm wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what each thing does.  First, the `test` script, slightly modified to add the shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo a
echo b >&2
```

The command `echo a` writes "a" to standard output.

The command `echo b` would write "b" to standard output.  But it is followed by the redirection operator `>&2`, sending the standard output of `echo` to the standard error of the containing script, `test`.

Consequently, the `test` script will first write "a" to its standard output, then write "b" to its standard error.

Next, we have the command:

```
./test >/dev/null
```

This runs `test`, but redirecting the standard output of `test` to `/dev/null`.  Consequently, the "a" is discarded, but the "b" is still printed to the console, since that is where the standard error of `test` is sent by default.

Finally, we have:

```
echo b >&2 >/dev/null
```

This runs `echo b`, which by itself would print "b" to its standard output.  Then the redirection operator `>&2` sends the standard output of `echo` to the standard error of the shell.  But then the second redirection operator `>/dev/null` sends the standard output of `echo` to a different place, namely `/dev/null`.  It's like assigning a variable to one value, then assigning it to another value; the second assignment is the one that takes effect.  Consequently there is no visible output.

Redirection operators are processed left to right.  Each one changes where some input or output *will* come from or go to, once the command is run.  Once all redirection operators have been processed, the command is actually invoked.

Conceptually, you can imagine that a command is a black box and the input and output file descriptors like standard input and standard output are little ports that can be connected.  There is a default set of connections (standard output of a box to the standard output of its container, etc.), but redirection changes those connections.  With this idea in mind, the following diagram illustrates the effect of the two commands:

[image: Pipe diagram of redirection commands]

In the second case, the operator `>&2` makes a connection from the standard output of `test` to the standard error of the shell, but that is immediately changed, so it has no effect.

I think you're confused by expecting both cases to behave the same because, in each case, in some sense, we do `>&2` then `>/dev/null`.  But because the operators are applied at different levels, they affect different processes, resulting in different behavior.

Comment: You made my day. What a wonderful explanation! I was just guessing in my head, but you made everything clear now. wish I had enough reputation points to upvote. This answer deserves huge upvotes, to be honest. I greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much!!